# Android, get all events of other applications in logcat?

Tags: android, root, logcat

How can I get logcat of all events of other applications in a rooted android phone? Actually I want to get if an activity is resumed, paused or destroyed in another application? I know there's not any direct method to do this,so I am trying to get these events in logcat.
I tried a test in terminal.

```
su
logcat
```

But I couldn't get desired information in logcat. 
I know how to apply it programatically in my application, I am using RootManager library for this purpose, but I don't know how to get this information in logcat.

Answer (score 0):

```
su
logcat -v long > /sdcard/test.log
```